# Identifing Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB

Tags: .net, windows-10

How can an application detect if it is running on Windows 10 Enterprise [LTSB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Long Term Servicing Branch)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GetProductInfo API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns that info.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
  public class Program
  {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Boolean GetProductInfo(
      Int32 dwOSMajorVersion,
      Int32 dwOSMinorVersion,
      Int32 dwSpMajorVersion,
      Int32 dwSpMinorVersion,
      out Int32 pdwReturnedProductType);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "FormatMessage", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Int32 FormatMessage(
      Int32 flags,
      IntPtr source,
      Int32 messageId,
      Int32 languageId,
      StringBuilder buffer,
      Int32 size,
      IntPtr arguments);

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
      /* Other product codes can be found on the help page for
         the GetProductInfo API function:
         https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx */

      const Int32 PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S = 0x7D;

      var productId = GetProductIdNumber();

      Console.Write("Product: ");
      Console.WriteLine(
        (productId == PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S)
        ? "Windows 10 LTSB"
        : "Product Number " + productId.ToString("X"));
    }

    private static Int32 GetProductIdNumber()
    {
      Int32 productId;

      if (GetProductInfo(
          Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major,
          Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor,
          0,
          0,
          out productId))
        return productId;
      else
        throw new Exception(GetSystemErrorMessage(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }

    private static String GetSystemErrorMessage(Int32 win32ErrorCode)
    {
      const Int32 formatMessageFromSystem = 0x00001000;
      const Int32 defaultLanguageID = 0;

      var buffer = new StringBuilder(256);
      var numberOfCharactersInBuffer = FormatMessage(formatMessageFromSystem, IntPtr.Zero, win32ErrorCode, defaultLanguageID, buffer, buffer.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);

      if (numberOfCharactersInBuffer > 0)
        return buffer.ToString().Trim();
      else
        return String.Concat("Error ", win32ErrorCode, " occurred.  No error description is available.");
    }
  }
}
```